# Why mariah carrey pronounce "infinity" song as "infinily"?

Tags: pronouns

Why mariah carrey pronounce  "infinity" song as "infinily"?

I think that I have not mistake listening.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO1CQhwCiG0

Comment: This is actually an artificial singing technique to help her carry the note through the "T" and into the long "EE".  There still is a "T" sound but the combination of the music with the lyrics mutes the reduced [*plosive*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plosive), which our ears naturally replace with an "L" sound.

Comment: To this US English speaker, she does not pronounce it "infinily".  But Andrew is right; she de-emphasizes the T so it's not so plosive, so it comes out more like *infini'y*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really about her style of singing. Singers can pronounce words however they want. Pronouncing words differently can reduce the tense from the throat. For example, instead of saying "day" as you normally would, you could pronounce it, at least in a different accent, as "di." This would lower the openness of vowels, so less strain in muscles.